# Why does PHP code starting with closing curly brace doesn't show errors? and why is it done?

Tags: php, html

I was looking at some web page code and at the end of the code there was a PHP part which started with a closing curly brace "}". Why is that? I am new to PHP. 
The code is for reference. Immediately before the else statement there's a curly brace. Please explain it.

```
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        if($_SESSION['admin_sid']==session_id())
        {
            header("location:admin-page.php");      
        }
        else{
            header("location:login.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: *tldr; There is a matching { up above. Somewhere.* PHP blocks can be intermixed with text (HTML); after all the in-between text is removed, the PHP blocks can be combined, and the pairing will be apparent. A good editor will allow easily navigating to the open brace.

Comment: there must have been an earlier `if(){`

Comment: In your code, `if(){  //some code ` is missing. if clause closing bracker and else block is there in code

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can split up the if else block to include HTML content in between to avoid using echo to print large HTML content. For example, :

```
<?php
  if(statement){
?> 

 // everything in here is shown if the statement is true
 <h1> Hello There</h1>
 <p> bla bla bla </p>

<?php
 //here ends the above if statement
  } 
<?
```

In your example, there must be a starting if statement above somewhere.

Comment: Thnak you. This helps alot. Is it possible only with 'if statement'? or it can be used to break php codes at any point in the page?

Comment: I tried to spit the code in to two portions and wrapped it in two "<?php ?>" tags and it didn't work. So I assume it works only with if statement. Am I right?